# Make change to selected object in many to many fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Order model and item model with many to many relationship, but I just want to make change to selected items for each Order, How can I do that? As when I get order.items.all will affect all the items in the Order.

Model.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
being_delivered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
Received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Received_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.product_name}"


class Order(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
   ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   being_delivered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   Received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   Received_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Views.py

```
def update_to_recevied(request, id):
order_item = get_object_or_404(OrderItem, id=id)
order_item.Received = True
order_item.Received_date = timezone.now()
order_item.save()
return redirect(...)
```

html:

```
 {% for item in order.items.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'update_to_recevied' id=item.id %}" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Received<br><span>{{ item.item.product_name }}</span></a>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected item by using post form then send it to  the views.py then resend it to the template as dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your goal correctly, But if you want to update only selected items you can use Jquery. Use a checkbox instead of a button,give an id to your checkbox

```
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Received</input>
```

you can check whether that item is checked or not like this :

```
  <script>
    $("#checkbox").change(function() {
       if(this.checked) {
    $.post("{% url 'update_to_recevied' item.id %}", {
    received: "True",    
    },
    });
}
 });
 </script>
```

or simply use :checked selector
https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

and you can take look at Jquery Post requests here
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp